# Default interface object

Tags: typescript

Is there any way to create a default interface object?

Example:

```
interface myInterface {
    A: string;
    B: string;
    C: number;
    D: CustomType; // A custom class
}
```

Usually you'd create an object of this interface by:

```
var myObj: myInterface = {
    A: "",
    B: "",
    C: 0,
    D: null
}
```

However it'd be nice if there was some syntactic sugar to do it like this:

```
var myObj = new myInterface;
// OR
var myObj = default(myInterface);
```

From my research I haven't found a way to do this; but I'm hoping that I've just missed something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there is not.

An interface-declaration only exists at compile-time, so the only time to do something like that is when compiling. Unfortunately, the compiler does not provide any language construct to do this, nor any way to extend the compilation process.

---

One way to get around this problem, would be to do some code-generation; Add a function that creates an object with the correct structure. The problem with this approach, is that you either have to parse TypeScript code, or some Domain Specific Language.

Read something like this:

```xml
<Definitions>
    <Interface Name="myInterface">
        <Member name="A" type="string"/>
        <Member name="B" type="string"/>
        <Member name="C" type="number"/>
        <Member name="D" type="CustomType"/>
    </Interface>
</Definitions>
```

And generate something like:

```typescript
interface myInterface {
    A: string;
    B: string;
    C: number;
    D: CustomType;
}

function InitMyInterface(obj?: any): myInterface {
    if (obj === undefined) obj = {};
    return {
        A: obj.A === undefined ? "" : obj.A,
        B: obj.B === undefined ? "" : obj.B,
        C: obj.C === undefined ? 0 : obj.C,
        D: obj.D === undefined ? null : obj.D, // or InitCustomType(obj.D)
    };
}
```

Comment: Bummer I thought that may be the case =(

Comment: It would be a nice piece to the compiler though if they were to add typescript syntax to do this though.  Aka default(myInterface) compiles down into a default object declaration.

Answer (score 14):

You can use a slightly different syntax and get all the type checking and IntelliSense.

```
interface IUserModel{
  Name: string;
  Age: number;
  Email: string;
  IsActive: boolean;
}

var user = <IUserModel>{};
```

You make an empty user object but TypeScript compiler is still checking that you have valid properties on the object and it still provides code completion.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To complete @Matija you can do it in one line too, and the your ide (for example visual studio code) auto complete it for you:

```
var user = <IUserModel>{
    Name : "foo";
};
```

It will help if you want to set Interface as parameter, so this is also valid (The `JQueryAjaxSettings` is an interface and part of `jquery.d.ts` can be get by `tsd install jquery` ):

```
jQuery.ajax("foo/bar",
    <JQueryAjaxSettings>{
        dataType:"json",
        cache : true,

    });
```